# PHP preg_grep multi files

Tags: arrays, preg-grep

how can I exclude more files like branding.php?
For example branding.php, about.php, contact.php.

```
$pages = preg_grep('/branding\.php/', glob("*.php"), PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use alternative in the regex:

```
$pages = preg_grep('/\b(?:branding|about|contact)\.php/', glob("*.php"), PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

Where

- `\b`   : word boundary to avoid matching `abranding` or `abc123about` ...
- `(?:branding|about|contact)` : non capture group that match `branding` OR `about` OR `contact` (you may add more files)

Comment: It doesn't work, man. Only my first code sample works well but that is no solution.